# Display only a single category on Wordpress homepage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a user review site built with Wordpress and can't seem to get just one category to show on home page.

I have tried:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $top_counter=1 ?>
<?php
    $blog_hero = of_get_option('blog_hero');
    if ($blog_hero && ! is_category()){
?>

<div class="clearfix row-fluid">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <h3>thanks stack-exchange help needed.</p>
        <br />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    }
?>

<div id="content" class="clearfix row-fluid">
    <div id="main" class="span8 clearfix" role="main">
        <? function customf_process_wp_query($posts_data,$post_type=null,$post_rate=null){

            wp_reset_query();
            query_posts($posts_data);

        ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php

            if($post_type==3){
                $in_top=false;
                foreach($post_rate as $key=>$top_post_id){
                if($top_post_id->ID==get_the_ID()) $in_top=true;
            }
            if($in_top) continue;
            }
        ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">
        <header>
```

Comment: I wrote a (very rudimentary) plugin for that: http://blog.friesoft.nl/2009/10/01/wordpress-plugin-show-only-1-category-on-homepage/

Comment: Thanks Ill try it but most plugins break my social sharing stuff.

Comment: Can I use this plugin to show posts from one cat on other pages? Thanks for your help

Comment: sure go ahead, it's all yours. Just give me credit in the code ;).

Comment: Hi it works on my other sites but breaks this one. I think I may have some code wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts( array('your-custom-taxonomy' => 'category name', 'post_type' => 'your_post_type_here') );
```

replace the above code with

```
query_posts($posts_data);
```

and replace **your-custom-taxonomy** and **your_post_type_here** with required arguments.
Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard loop initialiser:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Just change to:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() && the_category() == $home_page_cat ) : the_post(); ?>
```